# include GWT in jsp

Tags: jsp, gwt, include, forward, jspinclude

I need to include a GWT file into JSP page.

The GWT resource is the form of :

`GWTPage.jsp#browser-based_bookmark`

I've tried using `jsp:include` and `RequestDispatcher`, for jsp-include, it says `resrouce not  found`, and for RequestDispatcher, it returns `null`

Comment: Where in the directory tree is your `GWTPage.jsp` and where is the page including the GWT page? Are they on the same level? Please add the concrete code you tried to write.

Comment: In the same path as the `jsp` page.

Comment: The `.js` file loaded but if I included `GWTPage.jsp` not `GWTPage.jsp#someHref`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GWT runs on the client-side, so you cannot include `GWTPage.jsp~browser-based_bookmark`, as the `#browser-based_bookmark` is a client-side thing.

You have to include the GWT app in your JSP (either include some other JSP containing it, or simply the `<script>` pointing to your `*.nocache.js` file).
If you have to pass some state to the GWT app, use other means, such as global JS variables that can be read using JSNI or `Dictionary`.

See http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/articles/dynamic_host_page.html